# Log when a sequence is called for the next value

Tags: sql-server

I would like to know if there is a way to create a trigger or insert data in a log table when a sequence is called for the next value.

For example, we have a sequence Product Value that is shared between many environments and people is getting the next value for different things, when someone calls the NEXTVAL, I want to be notified with a trigger, log table or extended event that this happens.

Comment: The closest thing to this is the `metadata_persist_last_value_for_sequence` event, which, however, as the name implies, is fired only when a new block of values is allocated, not on every single value (unless you explicitly make your sequence `NO CACHE`, I suppose). Short of tracing every statement containing `NEXT VALUE FOR` and `sp_sequence_get_range`, there is no general way of doing this, and certainly no *efficient* way of doing this.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'll see what I can do